# How to get to the first 4 numbers of an int number ? and also the 5th and 6th numbers for example

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that checks if a date ( int number ) that is written in this format: "YYYYMMDD" is valid or not.

My question is how do i get to the first 4 numbers for example ( the year )?

the month ( the 5th and 6th number ) and the days.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be to convert it to a string and use substrings or regular expressions. If you need performance, use a combination of modulo and division by powers of 10 to extract the desired parts.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I understood how to extract the months, days and year.
my next question is, Im trying to think how i can validate the months.
( The possible values are 01 - 12 )
If its February ,
 I need to check if the year%4==0.
 If so, only 29 days in this month or else 28.
Also, How can i filter the ammount of days in each month ? for example i want 01, 05, 07, 08 to be 31 days  and the rest of the months ( excluding february ) to be 30 days.

Comment: my idea is to make a list like that:  [01, 02, 03,..,12].   filter the days to a variable called DD and write a loop on it. something like: if DD is in lst continue with the loop or else return invalid. thats the general idea i have atm. btw sorry for the unorganized text , im typing from a phone,and also im a beginner in coding so sry if i say stupid things

Comment: If you want to validate the date, why not use a library function? e.g. 
`datetime.datetime.strptime("20190230", "%Y%m%d")` throws an exception because of an invalid February date.

Comment: Its a homework assignment and we cant import functions from the library

Comment: If it's a homework assignment, then I would not ask for a solution on stack overflow ;) Any algorithm you will need can easily be found on Google and if all you do is translate it from another language to Python, you still learn something.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way converting to string then slicing it:

Example for year:

```
date = str(date) 
year = date[0:3]
```

for your example using the following format "YYYYMMDD"